# Ansible - Continue (not ignore) upon Failure

Tags: ansible

I'm aware of the `ignore_errors: yes` flag, to ignore failures during the playbook run, but I wish to know if there is anything in Ansible that I can set, that is not a 'ignore behavior' but still runs the playbook until it ends. That's because I want to have better report control.

To illustrate, currently this is my 'RUN-RECAP':

```
PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
<server>                  : ok=195  changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    **ignored=10**
```

The "ignored=10" is actually "failed checks"
What I need would be a PLAY RECAP like this:

```
PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
<server>                  : ok=195  changed=0    unreachable=0    **failed=10**    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Have you also set [ignore_unreachable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)?

Comment: The Failures are not due to unreachable hosts, but due to checks that fail or not in each run. It is OK that a check fails, I don't want to have the run aborted, but I also don't want to be listed as skipped with "ignored_*" but as failed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question

> if there is anything in Ansible that I can set, that is not a 'ignore behavior' but still runs the playbook until it ends.

you may have a look into [Error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html) and [Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) as

> Ansible lets you define what “failure” means in each task using the `failed_when` conditional.

as well [Handling errors with `block`s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#block-error-handling).

Comment: this is not in any way near what dumb admin asked!!!

Comment: @YosefSalmalian, regarding "_but I also don't want to be listed as skipped with `ignored` but as `failed`_" what would be near then? The [`assert` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html), [`fail` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html) or tweaking or [Developing an own Callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins)? I assume writing an plugin then. Maybe you can provide an answer here too.

Comment: there is no solution to this problem, maybe running tasks that may fail in different playbooks so they can fail...